# Анимация машинок

Tags: анимация, canvas, html, javascript

Привет. Стоит задача анимировать езду машинок по дороге (вид сверху) **не** используя флеш.  Я решил использовать canvas, и вроде что-то получилось, но с физикой у того, что получилось, явно нелады. Особенно плохо вышла анимация разворота и перестроения. Кто чем может помочь по теме?

Comment: А чем мы можем помочь по теме?

Comment: Может есть какие библиотеки для анимации автомобилей? Или хотя бы формулы по которым нужно анимировать?

Comment: Может jquery поможет?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [`box2dweb`][1] или [`CoffeePhysics.`][2] Второй из них лично мне кажется идеальным ввиду крайней простоты кода.

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/
[2]: https://github.com/soulwire/Coffee-Physics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это просто машинки, типа как для схемы проезда, то вполне сгодится [Трактриса](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Трактриса) для описания движения задней части. Передняя в среднем у всех машин движется по кругу с минимальным радиусом, равным длине автомобиля. (4-5 метров IRL)

Чтобы это закодить предлагаю разбить траекторию на участки. Повороты передней части будут осуществляться по линиям спряжения (их построить вообще легко: начало спряжения - катет прямоугольного треугольника, острый угол которого равен 180-угол_спряжения/2).

Затем рассчитываете всю траекторию и заносите в массив точек(с нужной кучностью). Движение от точки до точки осуществляете банальным animate. Перед поворотом машинку стоит слегка замедлить для реалистичности. Перед перестроением/обгоном - чуток ускорить.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь лучше обойтись без canvas

```
<img id="car" src="car.png" style="left: 0;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pause(ms) {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do {
            curDate = new Date();
        }
        while (curDate - date < ms);
    }

    var position = document.getElementById('car').style.left;

    while (position < 1000) {
        position = position + 1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Нельзя без канвы. Без нее невозможно плавно развернуть машинку. Спрайты слишком грубые, либо слишком тяжелые.

Comment: можно -
document.getElementById('car').scr = "car2.png" где car2.png - вид развёрнутой машинки